# how to negate a RegEx match using Data annotations in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have this expression

```
[RegularExpression(@"(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+)\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?", ErrorMessage = "Message cannot contain urls")]
```

It detects the urls as expected, but I need it to do the opposite.
The validation is only warning if I do NOT enter a url in the field. I need it to give me a warning if it detects the url saying that urls and links are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!.*?(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+)\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?).*$
```

Try this.This will not match url.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/8

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead `?!`

eg `(?!abc)`

mathces `hello` but does not matches `abc`

so your regex must be modified as

```
"^(?!(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+)\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)*/?)$"
```

Comment: hi mate, it is now matching the urls, but also everything else. Now if I write a normal text it triggers the validation. Any suggestions?

Comment: thanks for your help, however there was still something not quite right. The other answer worked as expected. Thanks anyway